# Text as fill pattern

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have created fill pattern, but if I put text into fill pattern, it is not displayed in the fill area.

If I draw a rectangle, I need text to fill the area of rectangle.

Should I draw text using lines making a vector text, or there's some other way?

Here's the fill pattern:
[image]

and here's fill result, text is not visible
[image]

Comment: As an example, from what I can tell you seem to want this https://i.imgur.com/NdkFSeg.jpg but you could want the actual *text itself* as the fill pattern.

Comment: @Mokubai exactly. I updated the question.

Comment: Okay. Gotcha. So you're setting up a custom fill pattern and then trying to apply text within that. It seems that this is a problem across versions of Visio as in my (probably older) version the pattern completely vanishes once I put some text in it. Without text I get a nice repeating pattern, with text I get an empty box.

Comment: Ah. If you create a shape and then double click that shape to add text then the text doesn't show up but the shape does. Much weirdness. Definitely seems to be limited to vector drawing so a makeshift stroke font seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I believe only images are supported ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/eu-es/help/295411/how-to-create-a-custom-fill-pattern-by-using-a-bitmap-image-in-visio)).

Comment: Thank you. Using images for text is ugly, I will create vector-type text using lines, and hopefully it will scale properly when saving as an image. I also considered using paint.net, but it converts text to image, causing the same quality issue as with Visio.